# Prevent assembly from being tampered

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, digital-signature, strongname

I produce an assembly already obfuscated and signed, built at .NET472 and .NET6 ( cross-platform). I'd like to add an internal method to check if the assembly has been modified.

Is there any benefit in checking this to prevent my DLL from being hacked?

Why [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named) says that there are no benefits to strong-name an assembly for .NET5+?

I found some topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369248/can-strong-naming-an-assembly-be-used-to-verify-the-assembly-author/369477#369477) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421513/best-method-to-check-that-a-file-hasnt-been-modified-or-altered?rq=3) but I'm wondering which is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: "prevent my DLL from being hacked" Eeeehm, what do you mean here? Of course as soon as your deliver a procuct - be it code or a wheel - you completely lose control over how that product is used. There's no effective way to prevent from misuse completely. You can make it harder (e.g. using obfuscation), though.

Comment: String-naming just produces some key based on the assemblies content. However the exact same key could also be generated independtly without knowing anything about your assembly at all. That's why relying on that key to be unbreakable is simply not a good idea.

Comment: Is it possible to compute the MD5 of the DLL file and store the result internally?

Comment: I found this, I don't know if it can be helpful for your goal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering

Comment: If you check your assembly integrity from within the assembly, it makes no sense. If the assembly was hacked, so your check could have been hacked. On Windows use the Trusted Platform Module (TPM) to store secure keys, e. g. for encrypting a hash. An example how to access TPM with .NET can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR. If it's really critical (e. g. for licencse protection), you can always use hardware-encoded keys with associated software like from https://www.wibu.com/products/protection-suite.html.

Comment: That doc link is pretty clear that strong naming only provides a unique identity. It's not the same as digital signing, even though it involves a private key. Just like HTTPS or any other PKI scenario, you need to verify that the *public key* is valid too, which means you need online access to a CA authority trusted by all clients. That's expensive, which is why it was never adopted outside driver development. You *can* sign your binaries digitally, provided you buy a [code signing certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/code-signing-cert-manage)

Comment: @borealis: isn't TPM available only on recent PCs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the assembly is already signed

Comment: With *what*? A self-signed certificate is useless, anyone could modify your code and resign it with their own. It has to be a trusted code signing certificate whose validity can be verified.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Yes, I know is impossible to completely prevent the assembly from being hacked, but I want to make it harder.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's signed with a trusted certificate

Comment: Then why are you asking about strong naming at all? *Code signing* has nothing to do with strong naming, nor does it use the same tools. I suspect you haven't understood the difference yet. In fact the real question seems to be about licensing, not anti-tampering. Otherwise the company antivirus would be the best option. You need obfuscation and anti-tampering if you don't trust the client

Comment: Licensing becomes a lot easier if you don't try to do it on the client but instead gather information about the current state of the binaries, machine etc and check it against a licensing server hosted eg on a cloud service. In mobile environments protection is provided by the App Store itself, which signs *and* verifies the binaries.

Comment: Using Native AOT deployment might make it harder to tamper with the code.

Comment: @abenci: Yes. If you are running Windows 11 you can be sure to have it, or you look it up in the system configuration.